# Examine the continuity of a function $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x \arctan(n \cot(x)))$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

If we know domain of function $\arctan(x),D_{1}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\cot(x),D_{2}=\mathbb{R}$ without $\{k\pi\}$ we need to check two cases:
$x<0$ and $x>0$

How to evaluate limits in these cases? When $x=0$ the limit doesn't exist. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is such that $\cot(x)>0$ then $f(x)=\frac{x \pi}{2}$. If $\cot(x)<0$ then $f(x)=-\frac{x \pi}{2}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: What about $x=0$? Limit doesn't exist?

Comment: $f(0)$ is not defined since $\cot(0)=\cos(0)/\sin(0)$ is not defined. (The problem is not related to the existence of the limit.)

Comment: How did you calculated the limits for $x<0$ and $x>0$?

Comment: I do not consider x>0 or x<0, but I consider x such that cot(x)>0 or such that cot x <0. Now if cot x >0 then n cot(x) tends to +infinity and then arctan (n cot(x)) tends to pi/2. and therefore f(x)=x(pi/2). If cot x<0 then n cot(x) tends to -infinity and then arctan (n cot(x)) tends to -pi/2. and therefore f(x)=-x(pi/2).

Comment: It remains the cases where cot(x)=0, but it is easy to see that for these cases $f(x)=0.$ (recall that arctan(0)=0.)

Comment: Domain of $f$ is $D_2$

Comment: Maybe you need the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $0$. But this is another question!

Comment: "If x is such that cot(x)>0 then f(x)=xπ/2". Well no. You could say $f(x) > x\cdot (\pi/4)$ for large $x$ however.